# How to know if a table has a non-unique clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, index

Give a user table ‘MyTable’. How to know whether the table contains a non-unique clustered index by using SQL query?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or some other product? If using SQL Server, then a uniquifier is added to insure that the clustered index is unique even if the definition is non-unique.

Comment: You really need to specify what product you are using (and probably which version).

Answer (score 4):

Create a simple table with a non-unique clustered index:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestCluster
(
    TestClusterID INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_TestCluster --note there is no "UNIQUE" keyword here
ON dbo.TestCluster(TestClusterID);
```

This query shows if the given index is unique or not:

```
SELECT SchemaName = s.name
    , TableName = o.name
    , IndexName = i.name
    , IndexType = i.type_desc
    , IsUnique = i.is_unique
FROM sys.indexes i
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE s.name = 'dbo'
    AND o.name = 'TestCluster'
    AND i.type_desc = 'CLUSTERED';
```

It's always vitally important that you specify/show the schema, as I have done above, since it very easy that objects with the same name might exist in multiple schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running SQLServer:

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS TableName ,
    name AS IndexName ,
    type_desc AS IndexType ,
    CASE WHEN is_unique = '1' THEN 'UNIQUE'
         WHEN is_unique = '0' THEN 'NON UNIQUE'
    END AS Index_Desc
FROM    sys.indexes
WHERE   type_desc = 'CLUSTERED'
    AND OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'MyTable';
```

Just one other method, but not better than [Max Vernon's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon) code, which gives the schema name too.